# The Type Of Person Who Might Appear

Tags: modal-verbs

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/might says:

3. MODAL VERB

You use "**might**" to indicate that something could happen or be true **in particular circumstances**. (emphasis mine)

a) *Your child **might** do better with a different teacher.*

b) *(He is) the type of person who **might** appear in a fashion magazine.*

Q1) I think the condition for sentence a) is: "*If she **had** a different teacher*." Am I right?

Q2) What is the condition for sentence b)?

Comment: What if the child already has two teachers? Consider the following sentence: *Your child **might** do better with **the other** teacher*. The meaning of *might* hasn't changed, but the meaning of the sentence has …

Comment: For b) the condition can be very vague and general, a la "if the right circumstances arose". It just means that the speaker thinks it's within the realm of possibility (in this case, probably because "he" is a fashionable or avant garde person).

Comment: The conditions can be many different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is sentence (***a***) re-worded as an if...then statement

> a) If your child had a different teacher, then your child **might** do better in school.

Sentence (**a**) could also be written as:

> All other things being the same (***cateris paribus***), your child's school work would be of equal, or higher quality, if your child had a better teacher than if their futuree teacher is the same as their current teacher.

Sentence ***b*** is not easily re-written in ***if-then*** form.

> b) He is the type of person who **might** appear in a fashion magazine.

Sentence ***b*** has a meaning similair to, "*he is handsome and good looking.*"  Another alternative is, "*he looks similair to the men whose photographs appear in fashion magazines*."

The following sentence is equivilant in meaning to the original (***b***):

> b) It is possible that he could appear in a fashion magazine.

The word "***could***" is a synonym of "***might***".

We could also write (***b***) as follows:

> b) It is not nessasary that he ***not*** appear in a fashion magazine.
>
> b) He is not dead and he is not ugly.

Suppose that "he" is a place-holder for the name "*Bob*".

We could write:

> for any person ***p*** if ***p*** is maximally similair to Bob, subject to the constraint that Bob and **p** have different levels of handsome-ness, then if ***p*** would be eligible for a job modeling for a fashion magazine then Bob would be eligible for the same job at the same fashion magazine.

If you really want "if... then," we could write:

> if **p** is a person, and if **p** applied to work as a fashion model for a fashion magazine, and if **p** and Bob were the same in as many respects as possible except that Bob and **p** had different looks, then if **p** would recieve an offer of acceptance, then **Bob** would recieve a letter of acceptance.

Let ***XS*** denote the set of all people.

Also, let ***PS*** denote the set of all predicates on elements of set ***XS***. For example **p** element of **XS** might be defined by p(x) = true if and only if person **x** was born in the year 2019.

> for any two **x** and **y** element of set ***XS***, if **x** is prettier than **y** and if **p(x) = p(y)** for all predicates **p** element of a maximal size set of predicates which are internally consistent and consistent with **x** prettier than **y**, then if **y** is a fashion, **x** is a fashion model.

A set of predicates **QS** is internally consistent if and only if there exist two people **x** and **y** such that **Q(x) = Q(y)** for every predicate **Q** in set **QS**.

A set of consistent predicates is "*maximal*" if adding one additional predicate to the set would cause there to not exist a person satisfying all predicates within the set.

The fact that person **x** is prettier than person **y** reduces the number of predicates such that p(x) = p(y).

We will have as many things be true about both two people as possible subject to the constraints that there exist people satisfying the unary predicates and the binary predicate "**x** is prettier than "**y**" is satisfied.